# How to increase RabbitMQ low publish rates performance

Tags: rabbitmq, benchmarking

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.6.10.
Having 16GB RAM on the machine and set water benchmark to 6GB. 4 cores.

I'm trying to perform some tests on Rabbit. Creating 1 publisher and no one that will consume the messages.

When creating 1 connection with 1 channel publishing unlimited messages one after another the management UI shows that average publish/s in ~4500.

When increasing the number of channels/connections and do it parallel in different kinds of combination i can see that it also not writing more than ~4,500.

I saw many benchmarks that talk about many more messages per second.
I can't figure what can cause the bottleneck? Any ideas?

In addition, when using many channels with many messages I get to some point that the Rabbit RAM is full and it blocks the publishers from publishing more messages. This is a good behavior but the problem is that the Rabbit stops writing to the disk and it stuck in this status forever. Any ideas?

Comment: The I/O  (network / disk / ...) could be the block. Are you sending the message in delivery_mode 2 (persistent) ? How big is the message ?

Comment: The messages are 117Kib. When sending the messages in persistent mode the publish rate is even slower around 1,500. I can see that the slowness occurred when Rabbitmq enter to "flow" mode but i can't understand why it is no writing more messages to disk in order to consume more messages from the client

Comment: Why are you testing with an old, unsupported version of RabbitMQ? You should use the latest RabbitMQ and Erlang version, and then use the PerfTest tool to run benchmarks (https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-perf-test/stable/htmlsingle/). More than likely the performance issue you see is due to how you have written your producing or consuming applications.